# C get the 2nd char in the 2nd element in array of strings

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers

I have an array of strings. How can I get the char "v" from the second element in the array?

```
char* name = "Ziv";
char* name2 = "Avinoam";
char* name3 = "Matan";

char** stringsArray[3] = { name, name2, name3 };
printf("v is: %c", *(stringsArray[1])[1]); // I want to get "v" from "Avinoam"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `stringsArray` is not correct, what you have is an array of pointers to pointer to `char`, you need an array of pointers to `char`:

```
char* stringsArray[] = {name, name2, name3};
```

Indexing is the same as in a 2D array, you could use pointer notation:

```
printf("v is: %c", *(*(stringsArray + 1) + 1));
```

But using square brackets is much clearer:

```
printf("v is: %c", stringsArray[1][1]);
```

Live sample: https://godbolt.org/z/TMjf1GcE9